# QuickJS Translate a Module Created with JS to C and Use it as a Builtin Module

Tags: compilation, include, quickjs

I read this article:  [Writing native modules in C for QuickJS engine](https://calbertts.medium.com/writing-native-modules-in-c-for-quickjs-engine-49043587f2e2)
.

But I can write the module faster and easier with JS. After creating the module, I can use import:

```js
import myModule from "./myModule.js";
```

But I don't want to move the module everywhere. Instead I want to use `qjsc` to convert the code to `myModule.c` or `myModule.o` first and then compile `qjs` and use it as a builtin module.

My expectation is to convert the js code to c with `qjsc` and then `make qjs` to include it in `qjs`, just like the `std` and `os` modules in QuickJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We discussed the issue here: [saghul/txiki.js#386](https://github.com/saghul/txiki.js/issues/386)